# Array undefined error and length function

Tags: javascript

Hi guys I'm hoping I can find some answers from your high skilled level experience.
I am filling this 2D array which I know how to do but I get this error:

script.js:35 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property '0' of undefined
at script.js:35

When I click on the error in the console it points at the number 2 in line 9 in this case: gameArray[row][column]= 2; am I supposed to declare the array as an integer array? and why can't I use gameArray[row].lenght instead of 5 as the condition in the third for of this code? Thank you so much guys

```js
var gameArray = new Array(5);
for (var i = 0; i < gameArray.length; i++) {
  gameArray[i] = new Array(4);
}
for (var row = 0; row < 6; row++) {
  for (var column = 0; column < 5; column++) {
    gameArray[row][column] = 2;
  }
}
console.log(gameArray);
```

Comment: 0-5 has 6 elements, not 5.

Comment: I actually found the cause of the error, the condition was supposed to be <5 in the second for. Lol what a mistake. I still can't find the answer to my second question though

Answer (score 1):

You would be better off using the relevant `length` properties of your arrays to control your loops - this stops you making an off-by-one error

```js
var gameArray = new Array(5);
for (var i = 0; i < gameArray.length; i++) {
  gameArray[i] = new Array(4);
}
for (var row = 0; row < gameArray.length; row++) {
  for (var column = 0; column < gameArray[row].length; column++) {
    gameArray[row][column] = 2;
  }
}
console.log(gameArray);
```

That said you can do this much easier

```js
var gameArray = new Array(5)
for(var i=0;i<gameArray.length;i++){
  gameArray[i] = new Array(4).fill(2);
}
console.log(gameArray)
```

Comment: Thank you I am really amazed about the much help I am getting, you guys rock!

Answer (score 0):

Your mistake is the typical off-by-one error.

You can avoid such problems using JavaScript array methods to create arrays:

```js
console.log(Array(5).fill(0).map(() => Array(4).fill(2)));
```

As you can see I don't use any index or length. Each element is initialized. I recommend to learn this code style because you will encounter it often in modern JavaScript code (I haven't seen a classic for loop in a real project for a long time).

Comment: Thank you very much, this is an amazing answer and tip!

Answer (score 0):

`gamearray` is an array of 5 elements while your for loop is for an array of 6 elements!
So modify the second for loop the first one and use the `length` property as upper bound of the for loop:

```html
var gameArray = new Array(5);
for (var i = 0; i < gameArray.length; i++) {
  gameArray[i] = new Array(4);
}
for (var row = 0; row < gameArray.length; row++) {
  for (var column = 0; column < gameArray[row].length; column++) {
    gameArray[row][column] = 2;
  }
}
console.log(gameArray);
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I owe you a Corona!